# Suppress or hide duplicate values in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I want to perform a select which returns a few columns of data, and then also a nested table of related rows from another table (actually the same table joined on itself but I *think* this is irrelevant).

So the data is something like this:

```
id  name   registered
1   Dan      N
2   Bill     N
3   Bob      N
4   Dan      N
5   Bill     Y
6   Dan      Y
```

The idea is to perform a select which finds all the unregistered people who could be related to a registered account.

So the result would look like

```
registered.id   name   notreg.id   name
  5             Bill     2          Bill
  6             Dan      1          Dan
                         4          Dan
```

I can handle all the selection criteria etc, and have a query that returns a normal inner join that finds this, but want to know if it's possible to get a result set kind of like this, so no repeated values on the left side?

Comment: If you wanted this as xml you could do it with the for xml attribute in ms-sql ...

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with SQL. You should do this in the front end application or reporting engine.

Comment: That would be nice but the query results are going straight through to jasper reports (which to be honest I haven't check to see if it could even handle these results, but now it's about the principle of whether you can do it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably better off suppressing duplicates in the Client (for example in Jasper Reports uncheck `Print Repeated Value` or in the XML set `isPrintRepeatedValues="false"`)

**However on anything that supports a `WITH` (CTE) and `ROW_NUMBER()` (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server 2005+) .**

```
WITH ns 
         AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rn, 
                    id, 
                    name, 
                    registered 
             FROM   t 
             WHERE  registered = 'N') 
    SELECT t.id, 
           t.name, 
           ns.id, 
           ns.name 
    FROM   ns 
           LEFT JOIN t 
             ON ns.name = t.name 
                AND t.registered = 'Y' 
                AND ns.rn = 1 
    WHERE  ns.name IN (SELECT name 
                       FROM   t 
                       WHERE  registered = 'Y')  
    
    ORDER  BY ns.name
```

[See working example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61669/sample-for-9320149)

**If you don't have WITH and ROW_NUMBER you can do this**

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.name, 
       ns.id, 
       ns.name 
FROM   t ns 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id, 
                         name 
                  FROM   t 
                  WHERE  registered = 'N' 
                  GROUP  BY name) MINNS 
         ON ns.id = MINNS.id 
       LEFT JOIN t 
         ON ns.name = t.name 
            AND t.registered = 'Y' 
            AND MINNS.id IS NOT NULL 
WHERE  ns.registered = 'N' 
       AND ns.name IN (SELECT name 
                       FROM   t 
                       WHERE  registered = 'Y') 
ORDER  BY ns.name, 
          ns.id
```

[See working example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61670/sample-for-9320149-no-with)

Comment: Thanks!! It was a bit of work using it on the real tables (my example was very simplified) but it does EXACTLY what i wanted! Thanks again for your help

Comment: And thanks for the Jasper report's tip as well, I'll have a look at that too.

Comment: +1. Very nicely done. :) I still think it belongs in the front end app or report, though.

Comment: @KenW hite Thanks. You're right this is one of those "you probably shouldn't but this is how..." solutions. For instance this solution would be really bad if on a report you want to suppress duplicate values *unless its on a new page*.  But its always nice to have another tool in the toolbox.

Comment: Agreed. Lots of tools in the box is always helpful. Never can tell when you might need a bigger hammer. <g>

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to do this in iReport, yes you can not print repeated values, but there is no I've found to not print repeated groups of values only if one value is repeated. The problem I get is it doesn't print repeated names even if they are different entities

Comment: A very nice trick with the reversed left join.. do not think as usual :)