# How can i display the Records without using Group_Concat function in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query:

```
SELECT tp.EMPCODE,
       tp.NAME,
       tp.DEPARTMENT, 
       Group_Concat(d.dte) AbsentDate, 
       COUNT(tp.EMPCODE) Totalnoofabsentdates
FROM test_prefixmaster tp
JOIN daterange25 d
LEFT JOIN test_prefixtransactions tpt 
       ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode) AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte
WHERE tpt.empcode IS NULL
GROUP BY tp.EMPCODE;
```

I have a String of Records like this

```
Empcode         AbsentDate

111             2012-11-12,2012-11-23,2012-12-22
```

My Requirement is to display thr Records like below:

```
Empcode          AbsentDate       
111              2012-11-12
                 2012-11-23
                 2012-12-22
```

How can i display  the Records in MySql?

Note:In My Query If I remove Group_Concat function then I'm displayed with 2012-11-12 record(2012-11-23,2012-12-22 are skipped)

Comment: Provide your query(ies).

Comment: You probably have your `GROUP BY` on `empcode`, if so, delete it.

Comment: If I remove GROUP BY ON EMPCODE i'm displayed with single record?

Comment: Are you missing an `ON` after your first join? Also, show the query you created that is only returning one date record.

Comment: Also table structures and relationships would be nice to have.

Comment: If you're looking to do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9320149/119477) but in MySQL you're better off doing it on the client. What is the client in this situation

Comment: @ConradFrix - That only works in SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: @Nicarus hmm did I say it did? In any case you're wrong the second solution works fine.

Comment: @ConradFrix - Not a personal attack on you - don't take it that way.

Comment: @Nicarus I didn't. I was just pointing out that you were wrong. BTW I wasn't aware that anything other than SQL Server supported  `SELECT ... INTO  #TEMP`

Comment: @ConradFrix - Suggest a correct solution if I am wrong, otherwise your are as useless as I am...

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this a shot, but you are missing some information - read my inline comments:

```
SELECT
    tp.EMPCODE,
    tp.NAME,
    tp.DEPARTMENT,
    d.dte AbsentDate
FROM
    test_prefixmaster tp
JOIN
    daterange25 d
    ON (tp.[foreignKey] = d.[someKey]) --You need to specify this...
LEFT JOIN
    test_prefixtransactions tpt
    ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
    AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte --Where is S_DateTime from?
WHERE
    tpt.empcode IS NULL;
```

If you don't want to repeat the `EMPCODE` value in every row, you can do this, though I am not sure why you would do this in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tempTable AS (
SELECT
    tp.EMPCODE,
    d.dte AbsentDate
INTO
    #tempTable
FROM
    test_prefixmaster tp
JOIN
    daterange25 d
    ON (tp.[foreignKey] = d.[someKey]) --You need to specify this...
LEFT JOIN
    test_prefixtransactions tpt
    ON (tp.EMPCODE = tpt.empcode)
    AND DATE(S_DateTime) = d.dte --Where is S_DateTime from?
WHERE
    tpt.empcode IS NULL;
);

SELECT
    CASE WHEN COUNT(b.AbsentDate) = 1 THEN a.EMPCODE ELSE '' END AS EMPCode,
    a.AbsentDate
FROM
    tempTable a
LEFT JOIN
    tempTable b
    ON  (a.EMPCODE = b.EMPCODE)
    AND (a.AbesentDate >= b.AbesentDate)
GROUP BY
    a.EMPCODE,
    a.AbsentDate
ORDER BY
    1,2;
```

Comment: If I Remove Group_Concat() function on Date column ,then I'm displayed with a Single Date @Nicarus,Remaining are Skipped

Comment: @user1929491 - see my updated answer. I don't think this is the appropriate way to handle this, but whatever.

Comment: I've used this statement in my original Query then I'm getting the result Group_Concat(d.dte order by d.dte SEPARATOR '\n')AbsentDate

Comment: @user1929491 - I don't understand what you mean by your last comment. When you run my last query, does it return what you want or not?