# Effect of LEFT JOIN SQL Statement on Performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

As We Know that LEFT JOIN SQL Statement gives All the Values from the LEFT table and the Joint values through an id (Foreign Key) from the Right Table. For Example I have the following table

```
comments
    comment_id
    parent_id
    comment_body
```

This table has the following data

```
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
comment_id | parent_id | comment_body      |
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
1          | NULL      | parent comment    | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
2          | 1         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
3          | NULL      | parent comment    | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
4          | 1         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
5          | 3         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
6          | 1         | parent comment    | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
7          | NULL      | parent comment    | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
8          | 1         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
9          | 7         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
10         | 3         | child comment     | 
-----------|-----------|-------------------|
```

for example i run the following query at the above table

```
SELECT c1 . * , c2 . * 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL
```

It will give the following output

```
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
comment_id | parent_id | comment_body  | comment_id | parent_id | comment_body  |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
1          | NULL      |parent comment | 1          | 1         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
1          | NULL      |parent comment | 4          | 1         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
1          | NULL      |parent comment | 6          | 1         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
1          | NULL      |parent comment | 8          | 1         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
3          | NULL      |parent comment | 5          | 3         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
3          | NULL      |parent comment | 10         | 3         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
7          | NULL      |parent comment | 9          | 7         | child comment |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|---------------|
```

Here I have Highlighted the Values, That are extra and I don't need them.

[image]

And in my opinion these extra values could be performance effective. Can I get the output in the following format

[image]

If it is not possible, Please guide me that what are the pros and cons of my above mentioned query?, and should I use it or not?

Comment: Your current, illustrations about result is a little false. Id numbers do not match to your SQL query and table data. Example first row should be: 
1 | NULL |parent comment | 2 | 1 | child comment

Comment: @AivarLuist You are right. It is my fault. But I take it as an example.

Comment: to me, left join is a pretty typical use, and I don't think you can do much with it, and what you want to do is not possible to my knowledge. are actually you having performance issue? have you try to indexing? is your table really big, so that it runs slowly? I think we may need more information around your problem.

Comment: @EthanLi! Actually, I have not implemented this code Yet. I want to know in advance that If I implement it, Will it cause to slow down my performance in future. As each LEFT JOIN has duplicate values of LEFT table as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Ok, I won't call it DUPLICATE VALUES. the value repeated is just because that for record comment_id = 4, it has a parent_id, which is 1, therefore sql join record comment_id = 1 to it. more effect you make to hide these values, will make query even slower. So if you bigest concern is speed, you can just change it to inner join (just swap the position of tables), or if you want to save memory usage for storing these data, then try to store them in a tree in your program

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this. But here is an alternate

```
SELECT 
    c1 . * , 
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.comment_id) AS comment_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.parent_id) AS parent_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c2.comment_body) AS comment_bodies
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL
```

This will give you output in this form

```
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
comment_id | parent_id | comment_body  | comment_id | parent_id | comment_body                                              |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
1          | NULL      |parent comment | 1,4,6,8    | 1,1,1,1   | child comment , child comment ,child comment,child comment|
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
3          | NULL      |parent comment | 5,10       | 3,3       | child comment ,child comment                              |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
7          | NULL      |parent comment | 9          | 7         | child comment                                             |
-----------|-----------|---------------|------------|-----------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

You can explode the columnm with php explode function to get comma seperated values transformed into an array.

[MySQL GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: While I am not sure that the savings in memory from doing this (rather than bringing back the left half of the join on multiple rows) are worthwhile this should work. But be aware that the default max size for the resulting column from GROUP_CONCAT is quite low. When the saving might be worthwhile is when the comments are very large, in which case the resulting concatenated comment will likely be massively over this size. Further with a free format comment you will need to use a separator for GROUP_CONCAT that will never exist in the comment

Comment: @Kickstart is right about the comment. there is no guarantee that the separator will never show in comment, as it is a text. also using the function will have impacts on performance as well

Answer (score 0):

I think u possibly need to check the below link for ur reference. It may help you..

[How do you suppress or hide duplicate values in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320149/how-do-you-suppress-or-hide-duplicate-values-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can allso use some more subqueries example:

```
SELECT 
    IF(c2.comment_id = c4.first_child, c1.comment_id, NULL) AS comment_id,
    IF(c2.comment_id = c4.first_child, c1.parent_id, NULL) AS parent_id,
    IF(c2.comment_id = c4.first_child, c1.comment_body, NULL) AS comment_body,
   c2.*
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
LEFT JOIN ( select c3.parent_id, MIN(c3.comment_id) AS first_child from comments as c3 WHERE c3.parent_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY c3.parent_id ) as c4 ON (c4.parent_id = c2.parent_id)
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL;
```

Example output:

```
comment_id | parent_id | comment_body   | comment_id | parent_id | comment_body
1          | NULL      | Parent Comment | 2          | 1         | Child Comment
NULL       | NULL      | NULL           | 4          | 1         | Child Comment
NULL       | NULL      | NULL           | 6          | 1         | Child Comment
NULL       | NULL      | NULL           | 8          | 1         | Child Comment
3          | NULL      | Parent Comment | 5          | 3         | Child Comment
NULL       | NULL      | NULL           | 10         | 3         | Child Comment
7          | NULL      | Parent Comment | 9          | 7         | Child Comment
```

Of course if you want performance, then such things will not help you. It will not make your query quicker.

As you have allso marked Tag PHP, and want to run quick queries with low cpu/memory usage and allso with using less bandwith (if mysql server is not in localhost). Then probably most wisest thing to do is make several queries And only ask what you really need from mysql, if tables are bigger. Probably you do not want to get all parents and child comments at once. And what will you do when your child comment is allso parent for some other comment ;-)