# Oracle SQL - Set null on repeating values

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help with below Oracle SQL query:

Tried several ways but didn't get expected results.

Data set:

```
ORDER_NO    ITEM CODE
1234      999999    777
1234      999999    111
1234      999999    777
1234      999999    111
```

Expected result:

```
ORDER_NO    ITEM     CODE
1234      999999      777
                      111
```

Comment: Please show what you tried

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind this requirement?

Comment: @Aleksej it's a pretty common report requirement. Many old school reporting tools support it. Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/9320149

Comment: You should really do this in the application layer and not in the database.

Comment: @Gary_W - I am learning - If you can't help that's ok.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Please see the answer how it can be handled at database level.

Comment: @Aleksej - Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you suppress or hide duplicate values in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320149/how-do-you-suppress-or-hide-duplicate-values-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make row number by `ROW_NUMBER` window function in a `CTE`, then use `CASE WHEN` to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   ORDER_NO INT,
   ITEM INT,
   CODE INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1234,999999,777);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1234,999999,111);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1234,999999,777);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1234,999999,111);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cteRn as (
  SELECT t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO,ITEM,CODE order by ORDER_NO) rn 
  FROM T t1
), cteGrp as (
  SELECT
       t1.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_NO,ITEM ORDER BY CODE desc) grp
  FROM cteRn t1
  WHERE rn = 1
)

SELECT  
     (CASE WHEN grp = 1 then ORDER_NO end) ORDER_NO,
     (CASE WHEN grp = 1 then ITEM end)  ITEM,
     CODE 
FROM cteGrp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60d707/28/0)**:

```
| ORDER_NO |   ITEM | CODE |
|----------|--------|------|
|     1234 | 999999 |  777 |
|   (null) | (null) |  111 |
```

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this for SQL Developer (which could be argued to be the application/presentation layer in this context) you can use [`break ... nodup`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve009.htm):

```
clear breaks
break on order_no nodup on item nodup

with your_table (order_no, item, code) as (
  select 1234, 999999, 777 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 111 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 777 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 111 from dual
)
select * from your_table;

  ORDER_NO       ITEM       CODE
---------- ---------- ----------
      1234     999999        777
                             111
                             777
                             111
```

With multiple orders and items:

```
with your_table (order_no, item, code) as (
  select 1234, 999999, 777 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 111 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 777 from dual
  union all select 1234, 999999, 111 from dual
  union all select 1235, 999999, 111 from dual
  union all select 1236, 999999, 111 from dual
  union all select 1236, 999998, 111 from dual
  union all select 1236, 999998, 111 from dual
)
select * from your_table;

  ORDER_NO       ITEM       CODE
---------- ---------- ----------
      1234     999999        777
                             111
                             777
                             111
      1235     999999        111
      1236     999999        111
      1236     999998        111
                             111
```